# Анимация изменения части текста

Tags: javascript, css, svg, анимация, css-animation

Хотел бы анимировать измение приставки **Раз**вернуть на **C**вернуть, а так же в обратную сторону, но только не знаю как. Это кнопка, которая должна открывать/скрывать контент.

```js
let openElem = document.querySelectorAll('.open');
let openSpan = document.querySelectorAll('.openSpan');

for (let i = 0; i < openElem.length; i++) {
    openElem[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        openElem[i].classList.toggle('active');
        function textAnimation(text) {
            requestAnimationFrame(function(){
                // Тут происходит анимация
                openSpan[i].innerHTML = text;
            });
        }
        if (openElem[i].classList.contains('active')) {
            textAnimation('C');
        } else {
            textAnimation('Раз')
        }
    });
}
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.open {
 -moz-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
  background-color: beige;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  
}

.openSpan {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a class="open"><span class="openSpan">Раз</span>вернуть</a>
```

Comment: @Sevastopol' абсолютно любым способом, чтобы что-то происходило, ездило, поворачивалось, переварачвалось, затемнялось и т.д., я не знаю что придумать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var abc = document.querySelector('.abc');

abc.addEventListener('click', function() {
  abc.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
:root {
  --atf: cubic-bezier(.58,-0.71,.41,1.55)
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.abc {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  perspective: 1000px;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ab {
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: 1s var(--atf);
}

.ab > div {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  text-align: end;
}

.b {
  transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateZ(90deg);
}

.c {
  transition: 1s var(--atf);
}

.abc.active .ab{
  transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateZ(90deg);
}

.abc.active .c {
  transform: rotateX(-360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="abc">
  <div class="ab">
    <div class="a">раз</div>
    <div class="b">с</div>
  </div>
  <div class="c">вернуть</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ой, спасибо большое, очень классно!

Comment: я не пойму, как избавиться от фиксированной ширины блока `.ab`? Чтобы при наведении на пустое место, нельзя было кликнуть на элемент

Comment: @МихаилКамахин ща какой-нибудь костыль придумаю )

Comment: я попробовал только позиционировать в пикселях, в процентах что-то не получается(или мало процентов задал, или у родителя не задавал сколько пикселей изначально)

Comment: @МихаилКамахин так пойдёт, или нужно что бы "вернуть" не смещалось? https://jsfiddle.net/jebghwz6/

Comment: Лучше бы без гридов, он мало где виден

Comment: @МихаилКамахин в смысле?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102999/discussion-between---and-hu-fo-of-ex).

Comment: без гридов https://jsfiddle.net/tv4hcr7x/

Comment: Да, так хорошо выглядит

Answer (score 3):

Код длинноват, но эффект печати текста выглядит интересно

`animation: animT2 1s steps(10, end)` вот ключ к анимации. В слове Развернуть 10 букв, нужно 10 шагов

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.b-container {
  margin: 25px auto;  
  padding: 15px 25px;
  max-width: 400px;
  background: #222;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.text-list,
.text-list li{
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1.25;  
}
.text-list > li {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  -webkit-animation: animT1 1s steps(10, end), animBlinkCaret 1s step-end 4s;
          animation: animT1 1s steps(10, end), animBlinkCaret 1s step-end 4s;
}
.text-list > li:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation: animT2 1s steps(10, end), animBlinkCaret 1s step-end 4s;
          animation: animT2 1s steps(10, end), animBlinkCaret 1s step-end 4s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
          animation-delay: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: backwards;
          animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animT1 {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 75px;
  }
}

@keyframes animT1 {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 75px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animT2 {
  from {
    width: 0%;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes animT2 {
  from {
    width: 0%;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animBlinkCaret {
  from,
  to {
    border-color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    border-color: #fff;
  }
}

@keyframes animBlinkCaret {
  from,
  to {
    border-color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    border-color: #fff;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="b-container">
  <pre>
  <ol class="text-list">
    <li><code>Развернуть</code></li>
    
  </ol>  
  </pre>
</div>
```

[Источник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/653407/28748)

Comment: Ходил по всему SO, видел этот ответ на ваш вопрос, но не знаю как анимировать своё. Я думаю, что в моём случае плохо подходит вид набора текста, как из строки, так как моя кнопка скрывает/открывает контент

Answer (score 3):

```js
const qwa = document.getElementById('qwa');
if (!qwa) throw new Error('!qwa');

qwa.onclick = () => {
  const els = qwa.getElementsByClassName('p');
  Array.from(els).forEach(el => {
    el.classList.toggle('active');
  });
};
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.open {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: beige;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.open {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: gray;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.open {
  --top: 4px;
}

.open span {
  top: var(--top);
}

.open>.t {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
}

.open>.p {
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
}

/** за анимацию отвечает это часть **/

.open>.p {
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
  top: -32px;
}
.open>.p.active {
  top: var(--top);
}
```

```html
<a class="open" id="qwa">
  <span class="p active">Раз</span>
  <span class="p">Два</span>
  <span class="t">вернуть</span>
</a>
```